# Codeception unit tests don't work with zend framework 1.12

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, codeception

I have zf1 project, which I wanted to populate with codeception unit tests, so I followed the instructions on https://codeception.com/docs/modules/ZF1.

Before I get too specific, can someone clarify this error message please when running a test:

```
include_once(): Failed opening 'Codeception/Subscriber/Zend/Controller/Front.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/application/../library:/var/www/html/application/plugins:/var/www/html/application/models:/var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library:/var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library:.:/usr/local/lib/php')
```

It says, that `Codeception/Subscriber/Zend/Controller/Front.php` is not found.
I installed codeception via composer, so I looked inside the vendor folder, but there isn' such a file. How can it be so?

Comment: you probably forgot a use statement somewhere

Comment: Please run codeception with -vvv flag and provide a complete stacktrace

Comment: Using ``-vvv`` the output says ``[Db] Connected to mydb``, so the connection to the database seems to work.